# How can I call a python script in a program written in C?

Tags: python, c

I have a Python script which is used like this

```sh
python script.py <filename>
```

This script does some stuff on a file and prints a message saying everything went well, otherwise an error message.

What I need is to be able to call that script in a C function in which I have the filename, like this:

```c
void call(char* filename){
    //call python script
}
```

Then I need to have the error message in my C function, but not only errors expected in the script, also coding errors like missing import or bad indentation.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can either link your program against the Python interpreter, or you can shell-out, using e.g. `system()` or `popen` which requires that the python interpreter is installed on the system.

Comment: Ok, but how can I get coding errors in the `C` function?